# In phpDoc, set a tag as a marker?

Tags: php, phpdoc

What I'd like to do is set a marker to be `@todo`, which is also a tag, such that I'll see todo items in the class/method reference **as well as** in a marker report.

Is this possible? When I try, my marker report is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Most IDE's like Netbeans or Eclipse support todo and Fixme tags like :

```
 // TODO:  do this and that
 // FIXME:  this is way too weird
```

It's rather a todo/fixme listview in the IDE than a documentation though.
(Netbeans > CTRL + 6 = Action Items)

Answer (score 0):

phpDocumentor, both 1.x and 2.x, recognize the @todo tag and produce TODO reports.  Off the top of my head, 1.x will also show the original @todo in the doc for the element that goes with that docblock.  I think 2.x does this also, but don't have a confirmation handy to be sure.  Getting Eclipse to see these requires that you add "@todo" to the list of marker strings, of which TODO and FIXME are preconfigured.